# SOAP API request works with Boomerang, but not with node-soap

Tags: node.js, wcf, soap, node-soap, aramex

I am trying to access the SOAP API which I am able to do using Boomerang easily. Here is the format of the request:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <v:ShipmentTrackingRequest>
            <v:ClientInfo>
                <v:UserName>myUsernameHere</v:UserName>
                <v:Password>myPasswordHere</v:Password>
                <v:Version>v1.0</v:Version>
                <v:AccountNumber>MyAccNumberHere</v:AccountNumber>
                <v:AccountPin>MyPinHere</v:AccountPin>
                <v:AccountEntity>XYZ</v:AccountEntity>
                <v:AccountCountryCode>XYZ</v:AccountCountryCode>
            </v:ClientInfo>
            <v:Transaction>
                <v:Reference1>001</v:Reference1>
                <v:Reference2>?</v:Reference2>
                <v:Reference3>?</v:Reference3>
                <v:Reference4>?</v:Reference4>
                <v:Reference5>?</v:Reference5>
            </v:Transaction>
            <v:Shipments>
                <arr:string>41496248135</arr:string>
            </v:Shipments>
            <v:GetLastTrackingUpdateOnly>true</v:GetLastTrackingUpdateOnly>
        </v:ShipmentTrackingRequest>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

The request gets me all the required information. But I want to make the same request using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap). Here is my code:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var url = 'aramex/aramex.wsdl';
var args =  [{
    ClientInfo: 
    {
        UserName: 'myUsernameHere',
        Password: 'myPasswordHere',
        Version: 'v1.0',
        AccountNumber: 'MyAccNumberHere',
        AccountPin: 'MyPinHere',
        AccountEntity: 'XYZ',
        AccountCountryCode: 'XYZ'        
    },
    Transaction: 
      { Reference1: '001' },

    Shipments: ['41496248135']
}];

app.get('/', function(req, res){

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
        client.TrackShipments(args, function(err, result, body) {
          res.send(result);
        });  
    });
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server Up");
})
```

All I get is a huge error in the `result`. The body of the `result` object is as follows:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'TrackShipments'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'ShipmentTrackingRequest' and namespace 'http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'ShipmentTrackingRequest' and namespace ''</faultstring><detail><ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException i:nil="true"/><Message>OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'ShipmentTrackingRequest' and namespace 'http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'ShipmentTrackingRequest' and namespace ''</Message><StackTrace> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)&#xD; at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)&#xD; at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)</StackTrace><Type>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</Type></InnerException><Message>Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'TrackShipments'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'ShipmentTrackingRequest' and namespace 'http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'ShipmentTrackingRequest' and namespace ''</Message><StackTrace> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)&#xD; at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD; at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD; at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD; at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD; at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><Type>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException</Type></ExceptionDetail></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it is still relevant, I encountered the same. Grab the latest WDSL file from Aramex's website.

Request args should be as follows:

```
let args =  [{
    ClientInfo: {
        UserName: 'myUsernameHere',
        Password: 'myPasswordHere',
        Version: 'v1.0',
        AccountNumber: 'MyAccNumberHere',
        AccountPin: 'MyPinHere',
        AccountEntity: 'XYZ',
        AccountCountryCode: 'XYZ'        
    },
    "Transaction": {
        "Reference1": "001",
        "Reference2": "002",
        "Reference3": "003",
        "Reference4": "004",
        "Reference5": "005"
    },
    "Shipments": {
            "string": awb
    },
    "GetLastTrackingUpdateOnly": false]
}];
```

The error you're getting is mainly because the wsdl parser is unable to match our args list with what is defined inside the WSDL file.

Comment: 'Shipments' for example should be an array of strings, so this is wrong.